# Creating an Archive gives me error as failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app while creating archive throws me error with exit code 1. Below is the screenshot for the same.

Not able to figure out the exact reason. Any suggestion will be of great help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgmNO.png)

Comment: what you have for "enable bitcode" ?

Comment: Clean(cmd + shift + k) project and try again.

Comment: yes i have cleaned the project, even deintegrated the pods and freshly installed it. But no success yet.